# Having troubles Django genieric UpdateView with UUID

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I am stuck with this problem for some hours now, I guess, I mad some dumb mistake, but I can't see it. 
I am trying to use UpdateView, like this way:

```
class ContributorEditView(UpdateView):
     model = Contributor
     template_name = "contributor/edit.html"
     slug_url_kwarg = 'uid'
     slug_field = 'uid'
     form_class = ContributorModelForm
     success_url = 'word/list'

     def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
         qs = super().get_queryset()
         print('args : ', args, " / ", kwargs)
         print('qs : ', qs)
         return qs
```

with this modelform :

```
class ContributorModelForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Contributor
         fields = '__all__'
```

and this basiest html to just check:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'contributor-edit' object.uid %}">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Update">
```

and my url is set as bellow:

```
path('edit/<uuid:uid>', views.ContributorEditView.as_view(), name='contributor-edit'),
```

I am getting this error bellow, and I trying at least to check if I have my uid at the get_queryset as an argument so I can manually perform the database queryset, but I have nothing.

> NoReverseMatch at /accounts/edit/40acc93b-538c-44aa-9493-56887b5b430d
>
> Reverse for 'contributor-edit' with no arguments not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried:
>   ['accounts\/edit\/(?P[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$']
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     http://localhost:8000/accounts/edit/40acc93b-538c-44aa-9493-56887b5b430d

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like you have another `{% url 'contributor-edit' ... %}` in your template, but *without* `object.uid`.

Comment: that was a commented part, but since html comment django was parsing it. 
I could have passed the hole week with it, thanks too much Willem